# 'Self referencing loop detected with type ...' error while adding entity to redis

Tags: c#, .net-core, caching, redis

I have an entity as `AppSlider` which has relation with `Action` entity. I want to Add an `AppSlider` and save it to `Redis`.

```
await _redisCacheClient.Db1.AddAsync<AppSlider>(cacheKey, appSlider);
```

But when I add it to redis I get Error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop
> detected with type 'MyApiName.Domain.AggregatesModel.AppSlider'.
> Path 'Action.AppSliders'.'

I already added below code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers()
  .AddNewtonsoftJson(x => 
     x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

However, this problem only occurs when saving to the Redis Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to reply to this one, might leave it here for someone else.

I am running Redis locally on a docker container for local development testing,
with the image redis:alpine3.16

Visual studio 2019 .Net Framework 4.6.1 Web application, with ADO.NET Data Providers - Devart.

My database context was set to enable `LazyLoading`.

After disabling `LazyLoading` the `self referencing loop detected` error is not appearing any longer as the Navigation Properties are now not being populated.

You might have to populate your Navigation properties if that is the case.

This solution might be very specific to my set-up.